# Populate Pyspark Dataframe Column with numbers in a range repeated equal number of times

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to populate a new column on the pyspark dataframe with a range of numbers , that is repeated approx. the same number of times depending on the size of the df.
For now, I am using the below code to generate random number between 1 and 3 and populate the new column. The problem is each number not being repeated equal number of times.

```py
df = df1.withColumn("random", func.round(rand()*(3-1)+1,0).cast('integer'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying `random` in whole dataset, which is truly random and you have less control on its distribution, you can use window function `row_number` while sorting your dataset randomly

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    .withColumn('_id', F.row_number().over(W.orderBy(F.rand())))
    .withColumn('_grp', F.col('_id') % 3 + 1)
    .show()
)
+---+---+---+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|_id|_grp|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  1|   2|
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  2|   3|
|  B|  C|  D|  A|  3|   1|
|  B|  C|  D|  E|  4|   2|
|  B|  C|  D|  A|  5|   3|
|  B|  C|  D|  E|  6|   1|
|  B|  C|  D|  E|  7|   2|
|  B|  C|  D|  E|  8|   3|
|  B|  C|  D|  A|  9|   1|
|  B|  C|  D|  A| 10|   2|
|  A|  B|  C|  D| 11|   3|
|  A|  B|  C|  D| 12|   1|
|  B|  C|  D|  E| 13|   2|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```